# MongoDB | How to show only non-empty collections?

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongodb-query

i know how to show all collections, but do not have any idea how to show non-empty collections. Any hint might make me appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you using the mongo cli? Or a library? I guess you could count the number of documents in every collection, and only yield the ones which return more than 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get / find collections which consist of no Documents in MongoDB, use below command.

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) { 
    var resultCount = db[collection].count(); 
    if(resultCount==0) { 
        print("Documents count: "+ resultCount +" for collection: "+ collection);
    } 
});
```

**Output:** `Documents count: 0 for collection : CUSTOMER`

To get or find all collection names with data count in MongoDB **uncomment if condition block** and `re-execute the code`.

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) { resultCount = db[collection].count(); print("Documents count: "+ resultCount +" for collection "+ collection); });
```

**Output:**

```
Documents count: 4 for collection ADDRESS
Documents count: 0 for collection CUSTOMER
Documents count: 12 for collection EMPLOYEE_DETAILS
Documents count: 30 for collection WALLET
Documents count: 5 for collection EMPLOYEE_STATUS
```

Comment: Perfect answer, appreciate it!